# Why dont exist the revit category attribute in JSON response from GET :urn/metadata/:guid/properties?

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

When I get the response from the endpoint https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-properties-GET/ of Revit Models upload in my bucket I also get a JSON with multiple objects inside it. This objects are (I guess) Revit elements and inside of each it appear all parameters of Revit elements (types and instances) except the Revit Category . i.e There are Family Parameter (name attribute) or Type Parameter (inside of Identity Data) but dont appear the Category! :/

Anyone knows why this happens?

I Attach some screenshot of the JSON response: [first part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OKGiX.png)
and [next part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pib6d.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not deeply familiar with Revit, but if by "Revit Categories" you mean things like "Roofs", "Basic Roof", or "Walls", those are not stored as properties, but they are represented by the tree you can see in the Model browser (in the screenshot on the left):

[image]

You can also get this tree in a JSON format from https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/urn-metadata-guid-GET/.